# Setting a 2-node local network with Internet access

Tags: ip, internet, gateway, routing

I want to set up a 2-node network. Both nodes are connected to a patch box and get their Internet access from there. Through their second NIC, the two nodes are also directly connected to each other as well. Here are the local IPs we want them to have:

- Node 1: 10.0.0.11
- Node 2: 10.0.0.31

And for the Internet, they both have valid direct IPs:

- Node 1: 128.174.240.91
- Node 2: 128.174.240.92

The default gateway for internet is 128.174.240.1

I've been banging my head for so long on this with no result. I am a novice in networking. I know some theory but can't really set up Ubuntu boxes, where you have things managed by Network Manager, and then files, and then another tool, and they collide, etc.

For now:
route -n for node 1:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         128.174.240.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp0s25
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     202    0        0 enp7s4
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp7s4
128.174.240.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s25
```

route -n for node 2:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0        128.174.240.1         0.0.0.0   UG     100    0        0 enp0s25
128.174.240.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s25
```

For both nodes, `enp0s25` is the interface to the Internet and `enp7s4` is the one for the local connection.

As of now, node 1 can access the internet but can't ping node 2 (ping returns `Destination Host Unreachable`). Node 2 can neither connect to the Internet nor node 1 (ping returns `unknown host`). The two nodes are completely identical; this is totally symmetric. We tried making the two routing tables identical, but it didnt work.

I brought in a skilled guy, he couldn't figure the problem either. Please do your best to help. I'm really stuck.

I'm ready to provide whatever output you want.

Comment: What is that? : `0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     202    0        0 enp7s4`

Comment: Should be removed right? But still we have a more specific route - the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Note: The following are based on a few assumptions I've made about your network: 1) I assume the netmask for your internet-enabled network is a /24 CIDR (e.g. a netmask of 255.255.255.0), and 2) I assume your gateway doesn't automatically provide DNS services, so we'll use Google DNS.

Check your /etc/network/interfaces file. For node 1, it should look something like:

```
auto enp0s25
iface enp0s25 inet static
address 128.174.240.91
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 128.174.240.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

auto enp7s4
iface enp7s4  inet static
address 10.0.0.11
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

For node 2:

```
auto enp0s25
iface enp0s25 inet static
address 128.174.240.92
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 128.174.240.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

auto enp7s4
iface enp7s4  inet static
address 10.0.0.31
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Then restart your networking by issuing the command:
`sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

Another note: If network-manager is enabled, it may interfere and change some settings. If you start noticing your networking behaviour change, it may be because of network-manager. I, personally, tend to uninstall network-manager, but you should be sure you know how to configure your own network-related settings.